# jQuery get data from HTML file table or Excel file

Tags: jquery, html, import-from-excel

Getting the text of an HTML file is quite simple using the jq .text() command as follows:

```
$('#myTable tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)').text();
```

However, I need to be able to apply it to get the data from a separate file, rather than a table within the page. So far have not been able to do it.

The file has a lot of data in it, so don't want to load the file into the page.

I'm also having a file size issue when converting the table from excel format to HTML. The HTML file is over 25MB, whereas the Excel file is less than 1MB.

It might, therefore, be better to have the data in an Excel format file and get it from there with a script, but so far I have found it difficult to do this by specifying the line and column.

I'm sure this is quite a simple thing to try and do really, so hopefully someone can give some advice.

A working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/p9SbP/119/

Comment: Is this a changing Excel file or a static one? If it is static, you could save it as .csv which you will not need a third party library to read. Are you planning on hosting the data file, having Javascript download it and load the data into a table? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The file will be static, and we will be hosting the data file. I want to be able to get the data from a specified cell within the file without having to load the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a plausible way to solve your problem: First, convert your data to JSON, as Javascript can interact with it nicely. Probably the easiest way to start would be to open the document in Excel, then go to the "Save As" menu and choose Comma Separated Values (.csv) from the type drop down list. There are many possible ways to convert from CSV to JSON. Perhaps the easiest is to get a website like [this](http://csvtojson.com/) to do the work for you.

Once it is in JSON format, Javascript/Jquery can read it easily like this:

```
function get_data()
{
    var request = $.get("json_data_url.json", {}, use_data, "json");
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Do something on failure
    }
}
function use_data(result)
{
    // Example usage
    var first_row = result[0];
    var second_row = result[1];
    var first_row_data = result[0].field_name;
    var second_row_data = result[1]['field_name'];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
        // Do something with each row like
        total_cost += parseInt(result[i].cost, 10);
    }
}
```

Note: The Javascript on the client will have to download the whole data file. If the data file is large enough that you want to prevent this, you will probably need some sort of a back end written in, for example, PHP or ASP to find the necessary data and return only that.